# Replicate CONCATENATE and IF excel formula in python

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, excel-formula

I have an Excel file which converts Hexadecimal value to Binary and Binary to Decimal and to String:

[image]

Using `Python` I'm able to replicate Hexadecimal to Binary using this code:

```
# reverse hex value
my_hexdata = "4FA73E84FA4B6C4A"
scale = 16 # equal to hexadecimal
bin(int(my_hexdata, scale))[2:].zfill(len(my_hexdata)*4)

## Result == 0100111110100111001111101000010011111010010010110110110001001010
```

The 3rd column of excel converts binary to decimal and to text. Which i'm trying to do in Python. I want to replicate this formula in to Python and I am unable to do it:

```
=CONCATENATE(CHAR(IF((BIN2DEC((MID(B2,58,7))))>32,
(BIN2DEC((MID(B2,58,7)))),32)),CHAR(IF((BIN2DEC((MID(B2,51,7))))>32,
(BIN2DEC((MID(B2,51,7)))),32)),CHAR(IF((BIN2DEC((MID(B2,44,7))))>32,
(BIN2DEC((MID(B2,44,7)))),32)),CHAR(IF((BIN2DEC((MID(B2,37,7))))>32,
(BIN2DEC((MID(B2,37,7)))),32)),CHAR(IF((BIN2DEC((MID(B2,30,7))))>32,
(BIN2DEC((MID(B2,30,7)))),32)),CHAR(IF((BIN2DEC((MID(B2,23,7))))>32,
(BIN2DEC((MID(B2,23,7)))),32)),CHAR(IF((BIN2DEC((MID(B2,16,7))))>32,
(BIN2DEC((MID(B2,16,7)))),32)),CHAR(IF((BIN2DEC((MID(B2,9,7))))>32,
(BIN2DEC((MID(B2,9,7)))),32)),CHAR(IF((BIN2DEC((MID(B2,2,7))))>32,
(BIN2DEC((MID(B2,2,7)))),32)))
```

My required result are these pairs of input hex values and their output text.

```
A426BC8C48E25A45    JD-FLPKRT    
A426B48F41251BE4    JD-BOBTXN    
6D66BC8C48E25A45    VM-FLPKRT    
6D66BC64389D0603    VM-640600    
6D66B6A0D0E0B8E4    VM-SPACEN
```

Comment: How would you convert a binary value to decimal using pencil and paper? Replicate that process in python.

Comment: @SolarMike I've Done it already Using Python, I just wanted to replicate that formula in Python. That's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a function:

```
def customHexConverter(hex_data):
    bin_str = bin(int(hex_data[::-1], 16))[2:].zfill(len(hex_data)*4)
    new_str = ""
    for index in range(1, len(bin_str), 7):
        chunk = bin_str[index : index + 7]
        if int(chunk, 2) > 32:
            new_str = chr(int(chunk, 2)) + new_str
    return new_str

print(customHexConverter("A4C6B4AF48E37AF4"))
print(customHexConverter("A426BC8C48E25A45"))
print(customHexConverter("A426B48F41251BE4"))
print(customHexConverter("6D66BC8C48E25A45"))
print(customHexConverter("6D66BC64389D0603"))
print(customHexConverter("6D66B6A0D0E0B8E4"))
```

If you're just dealing with the long binary string (per the input to the Excel formula) then the functional equivalent can be:

```
# reverse hex value
my_hexdata = "4FA73E84FA4B6C4A"
scale = 16 # equal to hexadecimal
bin_str = bin(int(my_hexdata, scale))[2:].zfill(len(my_hexdata)*4)

# convert to output
conversion = "".join(
    list(
        map(
            lambda chunk: chr(int(chunk, 2)) if (int(chunk, 2) > 32) else "", (
                    [bin_str[i:i+7] for i in range(1, len(bin_str), 7)][::-1]
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

Both examples are using the same approach.